# Геометрический блок с картинкой

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Возник вопрос при верстке такого блока, а именно как растянуть текст и картинку на всю ширину блока?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: минусовать не обязательно

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, Только я не понимаю как этот вопрос связан с выравниванием текста? Тут же вопрос об адаптивных наклонных блоках! Текста вообще может и не быть, как например

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, я Ваш и вопрос и ответ плюсую, конечно, но он не об этой ситуации.

Comment: Как я понимаю, тут что-то типа такого нужно - https://jsbin.com/suzopeb/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @HamSter  полигон рановато как пример показывать

Comment: @HamSter а я применил его в этой ситуации

Answer (score 1):

В общем по шагам 
1) создаём элемент .shape он будет с права обтекать текст и тем самым сдвигать его

2) изображение которое в контейнере и перекрыто двумя элементами border

я этот вопрос уже задавал ранее и мой ответ полностью его копирует:https://stackoverflow.com/a/38859507/6339052

**Лучше конечно такое делать на svg**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.shape {
  background: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 1.25em;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 560px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.imc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.imc:before {
  content: "";
  border-left: 50px solid #fff;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <span class="elems" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="shape" style="width: 9em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 8em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 7em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 6em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 5em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 4em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 3em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 2em"></div>
  <div class="shape" style="width: 1em"></div>
</span>
  <div class="text-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus </p>
  </div>
  <div class="imc"><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MdrHMjPr9SQ/VVEVzjy1f9I/AAAAAAAAAaw/GfefMa0KdV0/s1600/fashion-girl-ikoseomer-model-1408.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, отличное решение

Comment: тогда галочку :)